# Auto-incremented attribute assignment in sqlalchemy orm

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, orm

I have a table with the single auto-incremented field `id` of type `bigserial`:

```
create table user
(
    id bigserial
        primary key
);
```

I expect a new class instance to have a value of attribute 'id', but it is `None`:

```
>>> u = User()
>>> session.add(u)
>>> print(u.id)
None
```

However, if I execute a query statement, the attribute is there:

```
>>> session.query(User.id).all()
>>> print(u.id)
1
```

Why is field `id` empty on the first and not empty on the second call?

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#flushing) say that an "autoflush" occurs "When a `Query` is invoked to send SQL to the database". So your `session.query()` is triggering a `.flush()` which populates the autoincrement (bigserial) `id` value.

Comment: this is indeed the case @GordThompson!